# Best way to mount a floating L-shaped desk to a brick wall

Tags: brick, mounting, desk

I'm in the planning stages of building a new corner desk. I've started by measuring the corner of the room and planning the size, but I'm not sure what's the best way to mount it right now..

These are some sketchup renders of walls, desk, pc, monitors: [image: Sketchup render] [image]

Desk details

- Width of L two legs: 60cm (23.622")
- length of L the two legs: 272cm and 162cm  (107" and 63")
- material of the desk: 3 to 6 cm of plywood (1" to 2.5")
- monitors will be wall-mounted

Another way of building the desk is using 1cm (or 1.5cm) pipe (round or square, not sure yet), and place a 1.5cm layer of plywood over that.

Mounting surface details:

- the walls are brick (around 30cm / 11.8") with some hollow spaces in them
- the corner behind the monitors is a load-bearing, concrete with rebar
  (hope that is the right term of concrete with huge steel beams in it)
- the right wall has a window with an inside ledge
- above the window is also a load-bearing beam made of concrete with
  rebar

I was thinking of mounting two pieces of wood or metal to the walls, to create a lip the desk can rest on and a few L-shaped metal pieces that will hold the desk and prevent it from warping.

Am I on the right track? 
Thank you!

Comment: Get something with some legs on it. It will save you a ton of headaches now and in the future you can even move it around if you need to. Plus you won't have a wall to fixup in the event you do end up having to move.

Comment: Fixing the wall or doing some extra work are non-issues for me. The desk that has been there for the last couple of years has never been moved but it is too small for my work. Something with legs usually has something in the corner which I would bump when sliding with my chair or working on projects...

Answer (score 1):

Reading from other comments here - 1cm round or 1cm square pipe just sticking straight out of the wall on its own will not cut the mustard. You should be thinking of some type of right angle support bracket. With a 60cm side shelf, supported along the wall on a solidly mounted strip, that right angle bracket should come out under the shelf to at least 50cm and have a vertical side against the wall as far down as feasible. I would think that the vertical span of the bracket should be at least 20cm. The length of the third side of the triangular bracket would best be if it was full length but if the vertical and horizontal sides of the bracket were really sturdy then the angled side could be shorter.

[image]

Brackets like this could be purchased ready made or fabricated out of wood or metal.

Note that with brackets like this a good share of downward applied force at the outer edge of the shelf will get translated to pull out force on the mounting strip and the upper fasteners on the bracket edge against the wall. You will have to make sure to use fasteners into the brick that can withstand this pullout force with a good margin of safety to ensure that the shelf is secure. You should definitely be thinking in terms of someone coming along and trying to sit on the edge of the desk even is that is never the intention.

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea of using a "mounting strip". It'll be much more sturdy and make the installation easier. I have to wonder why the interior is brick, and why not a desk with legs? IKEA has some solid options for this.

Comment: The house was build with concrete and rebar for load bearing and the walls between the concrete pilons are filled with brick. Locally most use this way or build it only with brick, depending on size. IKEA does have some nice things but it's 600km away and they don't do deliveries. Also something custom fits in better with the rest of the room and will match the furniture. No legs it's something I like and while I can do it with legs, I'd rather not unless there's a good enough reason.

Comment: Sounds like you have a solid plan in that case. Also sounds like you're living in an awesome place which is either really warm, really wet, or both! I'd move forward with your design. You're going to need some serious brackets probably going as far as the outer edge to keep it up.

Comment: We got from -25 in the winter up to almost +40 in the summer. Lots of sun and lots of rain and snow also. Another idea I'm looking up now is using 1cm square or round pipe underneath the desk and mounting the steel pipes to the wall. Since it would be mounted on 2 sides to the wall and with L brackets it will probably hold... now to find out what is the the mechanical difference between round and square pipe...