# What fixing to use for hanging heavy structure to wall

Tags: hanging, shelf, fixings

I'm building an enclosed storage space above a staircase. The base would be fixed on three sides: on banister on one side (fixed to the floor, can take pretty much any load) and two walls on two more sides.  The walls are solid, combination of air brick and silicon brick. The base is made from an 18 mm thick plywood, and is approximately 80x80 cm. I expect the base plus whatever I'd store on it to be around 20-25 kg weight.

To fix it to the two walls, I'm planning to use L-shaped angle profile along the whole width, essentially creating the support for the base to lay on. The base will then be attached to this support using M6 bolts with nuts.  But what fixing should I use to attach the angle profile to the wall?

Again, these are two lengths of L-angle profile, about 80 cm in length each. Together with a fixed support on the third side, they need to support up to 25 kg in weight. My first thought was just usual wall plugs and screws, at least 30 mm into the wall, 4 along each of the two lengths.  Would this be sufficient?

Comment: Or this? [Mounting heavy shelves to brick wall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149635/mounting-heavy-shelves-to-brick-wall)

Comment: Or this? [How can I securely hang a very heavy object on wall made of hollow bricks?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/164514/how-can-i-securely-hang-a-very-heavy-object-on-wall-made-of-hollow-bricks)

Comment: Or this? [Best way to mount a floating L-shaped desk to a brick wall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/76772/best-way-to-mount-a-floating-l-shaped-desk-to-a-brick-wall)

Comment: [More yet](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+mount+to+brick+wall)

Answer (score 2):

Wall plugs into brick?  That seems entirely reasonable for a 40kg load.

If the load might be higher (eg: children) then brick screws, expanding bolts, or glue in anchors might be better.